# Whenever I clone the main branch of my git repository, Xcode marks three files for deletion

Tags: xcode, git, github

The files are just normal swiftui views and its always the same three. They are called "Footer.swift", "FooterButton.swift", and "Post.swift", and all reside in a group called "Components". It happens before I make any changes, just after I clone the repo from Xcode. Furthermore, "discard changes" on Xcode doesn't clear the deletions, but when I go to terminal and git reset --hard it gets rid of the changes. My team is having the same problem where Xcode always seems to randomly mark those three files for deletion.